# How to determine session finished in kafka streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am stuck in kafka streams and can not handle a scenario with DSL. Can someone please help.

Scenario:
I have a topic timeOff which has a key timeOffId and value of type object. Object also contain employee id which represents
that employee timeoff. So one employee can have multiple timeoffs.

```
TimeOffs 

timeoff1 {status:PENDING, employee: 1}
timeoff2 {status:PENDING, employee: 2}
timeoff3 {status:PENDING, employee: 3}
timeoff1 {status:APPROVED, employee: 1}
timeoff5 {status:PENDING, employee: 2}
timeoff3 {status:APPROVED, employee: 3}
timeoff6 {status:PENDING, employee: 1}
timeoff7 {status:PENDING, employee: 1}
timeoff8 {status:PENDING, employee: 2}
```

I want result as shown below, so that employee can have only his pending time offs:

```
employee1: [timeoff6, timeoff7] //as timeoff1 is already approved so don't need this now.
employee2: [timeoff2, timeoff5, timeoff8] //as all timeoffs for employee2 are pending
employee3: [] //No pending timeoffs
```

How do I go for that. I started doing this something like below code but I don't know am I doing it in a right way or not.

I don't need code but just suggest me correct/good approach of doing this through kafka streams DSL. Thank you.
In below example, I am streaming topic, and grouping timeoffs by employeeId. But in that case how do I get updated status of timeoff. I am confused. Can anyone help.

```
KStream<String, TimeOff> source = builder.stream(topic);
KTable<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>> newStore = source.groupBy((k, v) -> v.getEmployeeId())
        .aggregate(ArrayList::new,
                (key, value, aggregate) -> {
                    aggregate.add(value);
                    return aggregate;
                }, Materialized.<String, ArrayList<TimeOff>, KeyValueStore<Bytes, byte[]>>as("NewStore").withValueSerde(new TimeOffListSerde(new TimeOffSerde())));
```

Comment: I don't think this is best described/modelled as a session-tracking use-case; in KStreams, sessions model (streaming) event activity/inactivity with respect to some (grouping) key e.g. a user- or device-id. Here you seem to want to model a state-machine with resepct to some entity-id i.e. `timeOffId`; answer below for the latter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best approach is use Processor API.

You should implement your custom [`org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor`](https://kafka.apache.org/23/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/Processor.html). `Processor` will have state store to keep `TimeOffs` in pending status and when `Timeoff` with `APPROVED` status will arrive, entry from state store will be removed.

It will be something like that:

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.ProcessorContext;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.state.KeyValueStore;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CustomProcessor implements Processor<String, Timeoff> {

    protected KeyValueStore<String, List<Timeoff>> stateStore;
    private String storeName;

    public CustomProcessor(String storeName) {
        this.storeName = storeName;
    }

    @Override
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        stateStore = (KeyValueStore<String, List<Timeoff>>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String employeeId, Timeoff timeoff) {
        List<Timeoff> newTimeoffs = Optional.ofNullable(stateStore.get(employeeId)).map(timeoffs -> {
            if ("APPROVED".equals(timeoff.getStatus()))
                timeoffs.remove(employeeId);
            else
                timeoffs.add(timeoff);
            return timeoffs;
        }).orElse(Collections.singletonList(timeoff));
        stateStore.put(employeeId, newTimeoffs);
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: So are you suggesting this approach after implementing that aggregation part. I can also cover this aggregation part in Processor API too. right?

Comment: @Parkashkumar, yes, It should be instead of _aggregation_.

Comment: hm good one. Thank you for this one. Can I implement all this work  through DSL approach? If no , any reason for that?

Comment: @Parkashkumar, you can combine Processor API with DSL (https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#applying-processors-and-transformers-processor-api-integration)

Comment: @Parkashkumar, in your use case you need determine, that _session_ has finished (Approved status occured), be default Kafka Streams DSL doesn't support that.

Comment: Wow. Can you guide me some really good resources to hands on kafka streams. I am beginner to it. By the way thank you for all the information. :)

Comment: One small thing. you have used Collections.singletonList means immutable list. Any specific reason for that?

Comment: @Parkashkumar, No just some kind of container, you can use you custom one, but you have to remember about proper `Serdes`

Answer (score 0):

This can be entirely implemented in the DSL, and you almost had it; you just need to remove *approved* time-offs from your state object

Here's a rough example in Scala (because I have not written Java in many years, soz):

```scala
// These are just type-aliases e.g. TimeOffId is just a
// String, but has clearer semantics when reading type 
// definitions throughout the code
type TimeOffId = String
type EmployeeId = String

// Enums can get quite involved in Scala, so this is just illustrative
enum Status { Pending, Approved }

// This represents the value (stream event) object
case class TimeOff(status: Status, employeeId: EmployeeId)

// An alias for the state object followed by a factory for the initial state
// I use `Set` for easy membership manipulation
type PendingTimeOff = Set[TimeOffId]
object PendingTimeOff {
  def apply(): PendingTimeOff = Set.empty[TimeOffId]
}

// This is the aggregator function
def trackTimeOff: (EmployeeId, (TimeOffId, TimeOff), PendingTimeOff) => PendingTimeOff = {
  case (_, (timeOffId, TimeOff(Pending,  _)), pending) => pending + timeOffId
  case (_, (timeOffId, TimeOff(Approved, _)), pending) => pending - timeOffId
}

...

source
  // Map to retain the timeOffId
  .map { case (timeOffId, timeOff) => (timeOff.employeeId, (timeOffId, timeOff)) }
  // Now group by new key i.e. employeeId
  .groupByKey
  .aggregate(PendingTimeOff(), trackTimeOff)(Mat...)

...
```

You can probably recycle your `TimeOffListSerde`; if ordering is important, you could use a `SortedSet`, but be careful to handle `timeOff1`, `timeOff11` and `timeOff2` propertly